# Using tf.app.run() to call main function from a class

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

The question is simple, I'm trying to use tf.app.run() to call the main function in a class. But, the following code gives me an error. Any help is appreciated.

import tensorflow as tf
    import sys

```
# Where to find data
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('f1', '', 'feature 1')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('f2', '', 'feature 2')

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def main(self, args):
        print(FLAGS.__flag.iteritems())

def main(args):
    test = Test()
    test.main(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run(main)
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main)
  File "/Users/yaserkeneshloo/anaconda/envs/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "test.py", line 18, in main
    test.main(args)
  File "test.py", line 14, in main
    print(FLAGS.__flag.iteritems())
  File "/Users/yaserkeneshloo/anaconda/envs/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 85, in __getattr__
    return wrapped.__getattr__(name)
  File "/Users/yaserkeneshloo/anaconda/envs/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/absl/flags/_flagvalues.py", line 470, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _Test__flag
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when you try to access a property of FLAGS beginning with double underscore from inside a class, it prefixes the property with the class name. So instead of `FLAGS.__flags` it tries to find `FLAGS._Test__flags` which does not exist.

This is true for both setting or getting a value. So if you set the value from outside of the class, you have to prefix it with `_Test` (because you named your class `Test`.) If you set the flags inside the class, you don't need to prefix, because it does the prefixing automatically also on assigning a value.

So basically you have no problem at all with your code because your own flags don't start with double underscore, except you cannot use the internal `__flags` property to print all flags. You can access them individually though.

See the code below for detailed examples. (Also, the default value in the DEFINE line is the second parameter, not the third.)

```
# Where to find data
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('_Test__f1', 'feature 1', 'feature 1')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('__f2', 'feature 2', 'feature 2')

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS    

print( FLAGS.__f2 ) # prints "feature 2"

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def main(self, args):
        print( FLAGS.__f1 ) # prints "feature 1"
        FLAGS.__f1 = 'foobar' # assignment works the same way
        print( FLAGS.__f1 ) # prints "foobar"
        print( FLAGS.__f2 ) # AttributeError: _Test__f2

def main(args):
    test = Test()
    test.main(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run(main)
```

Comment: This makes sense, but what if you want to access the FLAGS variable globally, like in multiple classes? Just padding the name of class "Test" to FLAGS may solve the problem for class "Test" but it would still fail for another class, e.g. "Test2".
Also, having the FLAGS defined inside the class won't work since it won't be available to other classes.

Comment: This only affects flags that start with a double underscore. Just avoid using those and you'll be fine. The FLAGS (tf.app.flags.FLAGS) is a global, so you can access it inside any class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `FLAGS` doesn't have an attribute named `__flag`. If you want to print the string corresponding to the `f1` flag, call `print(FLAGS.f1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

# Where to find data
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('f1', '', 'feature 1')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('f2', '', 'feature 2')

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def main(self, args):
        flags = getattr(FLAGS,"__flags")
        print([(k,v) for (k,v) in flags.iteritems()])

def main(args):
    test = Test()
    test.main(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run(main)
```